# SingPath Quicksort Private Tests Failed

Tags: python, quicksort

I am learning Python using a website called SingPath. I am required to write quicksort, but  I am given the error:

> "Private Test Results: All the public tests passed but some private tests failed. You need to generalize your solution."

```
import random
def qsort(l):
  if len(l) <= 1:
    return l
  partition = l[random.randint(0,len(l)-1)]
  xx = [x for x in l if x < partition]
  yy = [x for x in l if x > partition]
  p = [x for x in l if x == partition]
  if type(l) != str:
    return qsort(xx) + p + qsort(yy)
  return ''.join(qsort(xx)+p+qsort(yy))
```

Any help on figuring out why this code would not be general enough would be much appreciated.

Two clues I have been thinking about are:

1. They mention runtime is checked in the problem description
2. They say when `qsort()` is given a string instead of a list it should have the ability to be returned as a list or as a string

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `join` expects a list of strings to concatenate, and you gave it a string concatenated already. So you did "adding" of strings, which you tried to avoid with separate `if`. Try

```
''.join([qsort(xx), p, qsort(yy)])
```